# How to connect to external address as other outgoing port number without proxy

Tags: windows, firewalls, ports, protocols

Is it possible to (mask / define) outgoing port locally on network without using a proxy?

```
default (outgoing protocol)
[address] [port]

set to (outgoing protocol)
[address] [selected port]
```

There could be a security vulnerability if this is not fixed and set as default configuration.

---

```
>Description | 

    [target program name] ➟ [selected outgoing port]
```

Comment: The ephemeral client port usually gets chosen pseudo-randomly when a packet is sent or a connection established, but can be specified by whatever program sends that packet/establishes a connection. Your question seems badly researched.

Comment: You don't understand what i'm trying to achieve here, plus randomizing port for every packet is just a waste of processor power

Comment: Ports get chosen by the system (pseudorandomly) whenever a socket is created, to be more precise. This might be for one-packet-throw away UDP packets every packet. But usually, UDP sockets as well as TCP sockets are longer lived than one packet. If I’m not understanding what you try to achieve, then be more verbose?

Comment: I'm trying to create a faster connection that's more stable and secure

Comment: wat. I mean, really: wat.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a perfect instance of an [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info). While you can limit the pool of ephemeral client ports your operating system is using to 1 and thus effectively setting the client port for every connection as you wish, you wouldn’t be fast enough to do so to not cause networking problems on the way (I.e. a web page load might open 20 connections in a very short period of time.)

It is completely unclear why you would want to do so, hence the xy problem reference.

As I stated in the comments:

Whenever a program uses the OS API to get a networking socket, it can either choose a port of its liking and handle the error if that port is busy or have the operating system draw from a range of ports that are available and allowed for that program to bind to.

In addition to the local choosing of source ports, there is this brand new concept of [Network address translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which does what you want as a side effect.

Lastly, it is not clear to me what security implications might stem from not having full control over source ports - not how that would be beneficial.

Comment: yes my question was hypothetical  because I don't know if this achieveable thats why I asked.
It would theoretically work if the source address allows the configuration